# Update with INNER JOIN with multiple matching values

Tags: sql, inner-join

What would happen if I update a table using INNER JOIN when the other table has multiple values matching the foreign key.

```
     update   
       customer 
     SET  
       customer.chosen_phone = phone.number
     FROM  
      customer c 
     INNER JOIN  
      phone p  
     ON  
      c.id = p.customer_id

customer
--------
id    chosen_phone
--    ------------ 
10    ?

phone
----- 
customer_id  number
-----------  ------
10           555-123-4567
10           888-999-0000
10           111-222-3333
```

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that the behaviour will depend on the RDBMS. But, the result would be that one of the values will be chosen arbitrarily

Comment: Do you have any further columns in the phone table that could help you to determine which to use? Ideally a preference indicated, but even a type such as Mobile / Home / Work and / or a timestamp it was added may be some help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are working on. Just tried this in Oracle and it returns an error 'single row sub query returns multiple rows'. As I suggested in the comments on the question, I would suggest looking for ways that you can determine the most appropriate phone number.

Answer (score 0):

In your case UPDATE will run 3 times
1) Phone will update to 555-123-4567
2) Phone will update to 888-999-0000
3) Phone will update to 111-222-3333